# Where is the phantomjs core dumped

Tags: ubuntu, phantomjs

I get this error

`PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Does this mean that a file with the error has been dumped somewhere? If so, where? Nothing found in the current work dir og /tmp.

`# ./bin/phantomjs --version
2.1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of your `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file.

If it starts with `|`, then the core dump's output is treated as input for following pattern. (More on this [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt))

If it is `/tmp` and the file is still not there, some `chdir` operation in a thread could've been called before the segmentation fault. If so, check the working directory of the phantomjs binary inside it's `node_modules` directory.

Comment: `# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P`

Comment: This means that the code dump's output is being piped to apport.

Change the `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` content to `/tmp`  and run phantomjs to have a core dump file in `/tmp`